# Why I am able to execute this it is showing ran 0 tests

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class Environment(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\auto\chromedriver.exe")

    def test_login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("htt://localhost/dashboard/user/login")
        username = driver.find_element_by_id("uemail")
        username.send_keys("xyz@abc.com")
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("upwd")
        password.send_keys("1234567890")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('upwd').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

Comment: Because the indentation is wrong, you're trying to run the tests from inside the test class, *before* you've finished defining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\Downloads\\New folder (2)\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: it is not going in function

Comment: your url is not going to work for me because It's hosted on your local machine. please refer above example and make changes accordingly: – dbachhav

Comment: when i have executed without function then it ran successfully

Comment: first tell me are you able to execute above code without any issue?

Comment: How you are executing your test?

Comment: Now I could able to execute but when we change the function name it is not executing